# Ctools form submission json response broken by VPN

Tags: 7, forms, chaos-tool-suite

I have a ctools modal form implementation in my intranet site which works normally within the office premises. However when accessed from outside using a VPN, the submission seemed to fail without showing the success message. We then discovered that the form submission response through VPN contained script tags appended to it like

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" id="dsshim" src="/dana-cached/js/shimdata.cgi"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" id="dstimeout" src="/dana-cached/js/sessiontimeout.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" id="dsvar" >
//<![CDATA[......[{"command"...
```

This causes error in parsing the json response and makes it look like the form submission is still in process instead of showing the form submission message.

While looking for similar issues I came across [this](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-33680?focusedCommentId=191477&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-191477) thread reporting on the same problem stating that the script tags would be appended while using *Content type: text/html* and should use *application/json* instead.

I am currently checking for ways on the drupal end to prevent this from occurring and would appreciate suggestions on the same.

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you saying that Drupal is adding these script tags somehow?

Comment: Apologies if the query wasn't clear. No, the script tags are appended by the VPN (apparently because the ajax response content type is text/html).. because I can't do anything about the VPN I'm trying to see if there's a way to prevent the js error

Comment: I very much doubt it from Drupal's end - if it's a MIME type problem your server config would need to take care of that

Comment: that seems to be where i'm headed but was really curious if someone else  encountered the same problem